# Reaction rate constants for methane combustion

Tags: kinetics, combustion, reference-request

I can't find a rate constant or activation energy for the methane combustion reaction given by:

$$\ce{ CH4 + 2O2 -> CO2 + 2H2O}$$

Do all reactions have a rate constant? The [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/) web site lists several rate constants for reactions of methane that yield other products, but none for the reaction above. Is there a known rate constant for the reaction given above?

Comment: Very good question. The reaction you have is the sum of several intermediate reactions, and many of them have been quantified in terms of their kinetics. [This publication](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100540a031?journalCode=jpchax) is a bit dated but offers a wide overview of the type of problem you have. Additionally, and sentimentally for me, it is co-authored by Bill Gardiner, with whom I spent countless hours in graduate school, as his TA for physical chemistry and as his friend.

Comment: [This](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S1877705816310281/1-s2.0-S1877705816310281-main.pdf?_tid=b371b06a-1674-11e8-8f92-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1519155292_94caef7328bd3a3de7b80ac88f699eb6) looks pretty good.